# Typescript: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type "{ [key: string]: any; }"

Tags: typescript

I'm making a function that adds an additional property to each element of the array:

```js
type AnyObj = { [key: string]: any };

function addIndexProp<T extends AnyObj>(
  obj: T[],
  myProp: string
): T[] {
  return obj.map(item => {
    item[myProp] = 'myProp';
    return item;
  });
}
```

But I got the following error:

```sh
$ tsc --noEmit src/test.ts
src/test.ts:8:5 - error TS2536: Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.

8     item[myProp] = 'myProp';
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.

error Command failed with exit code 1
```

I don't understand why this happens because I alreay specified T using a string index type, and especially the following code works well:

```
const test: { [key: string]: any } = { test: 1 };
const myProp = 'prop';
test[myProp] = 'myProp';
```

Does anyone have an idea why the first snippet throws an error, and how to workaround the problem? Thanks!

Comment: BTW your code will be more readable if you move the inline type-definition to a `type` statement.

Comment: @Dai Right. Thanks for pointing me out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with `T extends AnyObj` is that `T` can be anything to which a value of `AnyObj` is assignable, and TypeScript will give [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#implicit-index-signatures) to object literal types whose properties match the index signature property.  So a type like `{a: number}` is assignable to `AnyObj`, despite not having an index signature.  So you can write the following code without error:

```
let obj = { a: 123, b: 345 };
const addedProps = addIndexProp([obj], "a");
addedProps[0].a.toFixed(); // okay at compile time, error at runtime
```

Inside `addIndexProp()`, the problematic line ends up assigning a value `"myProp"` to a property that's supposed to be of type `number`.  And that's not good.

---

The right fix really depends on your use cases.  If you just want to make the compiler happy without actually making your code any safer, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  This will just let you assign `item[myProp]="myProp"` even if `myProp` clobbers existing properties:

```
function addIndexPropAssert<T extends AnyObj>(
  obj: T[],
  myProp: string
): T[] {
  return obj.map(item => {
    (item as any)[myProp] = 'myProp';
    return item;
  });
}
```

The *safest* thing to do is not to mutate the original `obj` elements and to use more expressive types to indicate that you are adding or overwriting the `[myProp]` property of `T`:

```
function addIndexPropDoNotModify<T, K extends PropertyKey>(obj: T[], myProp: K) {
  return obj.map((item: Omit<T, K>) => expandType(Object.assign(
    { [myProp]: "myProp" } as Record<K, string>,
    item
  )));
}
```

Here we are using `Object.assign()` where the target is a new object, so no existing objects get modified.  The type will end up being an array of the intersection of `Omit<T, K>` (meaning `T` with the `[myProp]` property removed) with `Record<K, string>` (meaning the `[myProp]` property has been added back in with a `string` value).

And `expandType()` is just a helper function that convinces the compiler to turn an ugly intersection of mapped types like `Omit<{a: number, b: number}, "a"> & Record<"a", string>` into a more straightforward type like `{a: string, b: number}`, like this:

```
function expandType<T>(x: T) {
  return x as any as T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: T[K] } : never;
}
```

Here's how it works:

```
let obj2 = { a: 123, b: 345 }; // {a: number, b: number}
const addedProps2 = addIndexPropDoNotModify([obj2], "a"); // Array<{a: string, b: number}>
addedProps2[0].a.toFixed(); // caught error at compile time, toFixed does not exist on string
```

So the difference here is that `addedProps2`'s elements are now seen to be of type `{a: string, b: number}` even though `obj` is of type `{a: number, b: number}`.

Anyway hope that one of those will help give you some direction.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdiA8gIwFZQLxQN5QNoDWEIAXFAM7ABOAlnAOYC6ZAhglAL4DcAsAFD8AZgFc4AY2A0A9nCgsAJvICSceRAAeABSpSwAHgAqUDcAirysBClQA+ABT8oUKWjIG8jADSOoAWxDaumSUtAz8AJRuHjg+VBDAwlSyLqgAdL4sYHY0pr6YNjF8Tk45EL54-oFgjJhQAOSVOmB1vEXFcQlJUKW+rU4c4a0c-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)